# Is there a way that the window constantly sends its state (open or closed) in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This throws me an error: the windows method is not recognized. I'm trying to get the method to inform me if the Toplevel window is open or closed so that I don't open it again, (disable) is not a valid option. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```py
class classA ():

   def__init__(self):

      self.root = Tk()

      btn = Button(self.root, 
      text="New window", 
      command=self.windows).pack()

      self.windows.opened = False

      self.root.mainloop()

   def windows():

      if (self.windows.opened):
         return

      self.windows.opened = True

      root2 = Toplevel(self.root)

      root2. wait_window()

      self.windows.opened = False

app = classA()
```

Comment: Why don't you have a `self` inside `def windows()`? Please look at some object oriented programming tutorials that focus on python.

Comment: I was wondering if there is an integrated method in tkinter to know the status of the windows (open or closed), since the code I send does not give problems if I remove the self and do not use classes.

Comment: use `def window(self)` as @TheLizzard stated and take a look at some OOP tutorials, also for such things why haven't you looked at some docs? if such function isn't in the docs then maybe it doesn't exist: here are some [unofficial docs (that are pretty good)](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/) but you can also take a look at the official ones that should include all of the functions for sure

Comment: I was only looking for a suggestion since I have looked in the tkinter doc but it is very little documented, I have tried with winfo_ismapped, exist, protocols but there is not one when a window is opened. Well I thought that the older community could give me light on the subject but thanks anyway.

Comment: @RicharP Why not use a variable to track if the window is open/closed?

Comment: When you say "closed", what do you mean? That the window has been destroyed, or that the window is invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code so that `Toplevel` can only be created once!

```py
import tkinter as tk

class classA:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        btn = tk.Button(self.root, text="New window", command=self.windows)
        btn.pack()

    def windows(self):
        try:
            self.root2.winfo_viewable()
        except Exception as err:
            self.root2 = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
            self.root2.transient( self.root )
        else:
            print( "Toplevel created" )

app = classA()
app.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no need for the `self.root.update()`. Also using `except Exception` is bad practise and I can't see a point to the `self.root.deiconify()`.